# Why colorscheme is re-loaded if vimrc is located in $VIM?

Tags: colorscheme

I ran into a problem with cursor color being reset when using gruvbox color scheme on both Linux and Windows. During debugging I discovered that the **color scheme is reloaded if vimrc is located in $VIM**. In my test case I have **only two user files**: **vimrc** and **$VIM/vimfiles/colors/kgb.vim** (the rest is the standard vim installation). I set **VIMINIT** to ***"source $VIM\vimrc"*** to control which vimrc is loaded.

```
set|grep VIM
MYVIMRC=C:\Users\Public\Vim\vimrc
VIM=C:\Users\Public\Vim
VIMINIT=source C:\Users\Public\Vim\vimrc
VIMRUNTIME=E:\Vim\vim81
```

```
cd %VIM%

find vim*
vimfiles
vimfiles/colors
vimfiles/colors/kgb.vim
vimrc

cat vimrc
echomsg "Before colo: " . execute("colo")
color kgb
echomsg "After colo: " . execute("colo")

cat vimfiles/colors/kgb.vim
echomsg "Executing script: " . expand("<sfile>")
let g:colors_name="kgb"
```

```
gvim.exe
```

```
:mes
Before colo: ^@default
Executing script: C:\Users\Public\Vim\vimfiles\colors\kgb.vim
After colo: ^@kgb
Before colo: ^@kgb
Executing script: C:\Users\Public\Vim\vimfiles\colors\kgb.vim
After colo: ^@kgb
Executing script: C:\Users\Public\Vim\vimfiles\colors\kgb.vim
```

NOTE: The above output shows that vimrc is loaded twice and colorscheme is loaded three times in Windows (only two times on Linux). If VIMINIT is not set and vimrc is located in $VIM, then vimrc is loaded only once, but colorsheme is still loaded twice on both Windows and Linux.

```
:scr
  1: C:\Users\Public\Vim\vimrc
  2: C:\Users\Public\Vim\vimfiles\colors\kgb.vim
  3: E:\Vim\vim81\plugin\getscriptPlugin.vim
  4: E:\Vim\vim81\plugin\gzip.vim
  5: E:\Vim\vim81\plugin\logiPat.vim
  6: E:\Vim\vim81\plugin\manpager.vim
  7: E:\Vim\vim81\plugin\matchparen.vim
  8: E:\Vim\vim81\plugin\netrwPlugin.vim
  9: E:\Vim\vim81\plugin\rrhelper.vim
 10: E:\Vim\vim81\plugin\spellfile.vim
 11: E:\Vim\vim81\plugin\tarPlugin.vim
 12: E:\Vim\vim81\plugin\tohtml.vim
 13: E:\Vim\vim81\plugin\vimballPlugin.vim
 14: E:\Vim\vim81\plugin\zipPlugin.vim
 15: E:\Vim\vim81\menu.vim
 16: E:\Vim\vim81\autoload\paste.vim
```

```
:quit
Error:
Executing script: C:\Users\Public\Vim\vimfiles\colors\kgb.vim
```

If I move vimrc under vimfiles and set **VIMINIT="source $VIM\vimfiles\vimrc"** the scheme is loaded only once:

```
set|grep VIM
MYVIMRC=C:\Users\Public\Vim\vimfiles\vimrc
VIM=C:\Users\Public\Vim
VIMINIT=source C:\Users\Public\Vim\vimfiles\vimrc
VIMRUNTIME=E:\Vim\vim81
```

```
gvim.exe
```

```
:mes
Before colo: ^@default
Executing script: C:\Users\Public\Vim\vimfiles\colors\kgb.vim
After colo: ^@kgb
Executing script: C:\Users\Public\Vim\vimfiles\colors\kgb.vim
```

```
:quit
Error:
Executing script: C:\Users\Public\Vim\vimfiles\colors\kgb.vim
```

**Any explanation why this is happening?**

Comment: `$HOME` is searched first anyway. So what's the reason to set `$VIM` after all?

Comment: $VIM can point to a single location mounted from multiple clients, which have different access path.

Comment: @user1602 Your question now contains 6 different possible configurations, with multiple different sets of resulting behaviour, but only includes the full output for one of these (and doesn't state for which configuration the output applies), which makes it quite hard to nail down the precise issue! If you could either include the full output for all the configurations you are asking about or, better yet, narrow down your question a bit, it would make it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why the colorscheme is loaded twice

This is slightly speculative, since your excellent and detailed question nevertheless still doesn't contain quite enough information about your setup to be certain, but I believe what is happening is this:

1. When Vim starts up, one of the first things it does is load your `$VIM/vimrc` file, which loads your colorscheme, thus setting `g:colors_name`. **However, note that `$VIM/vimrc` is *not* considered a user vimrc file, but is instead a *system* vimrc**. (See [`:help system-vimrc`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#system-vimrc) and check the output of `:version` to confirm that Vim is using this location for its system vimrc.)
2. Presuming you don't have another `vimrc` in any of the locations described in [`:help _vimrc`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#_vimrc) point **3.c.II**, then Vim will then load the `defaults.vim` file, as described in point **3.c.V**, because no *user* vimrc has been found.
3. `defaults.vim` executes the command `:syntax on`, [which sources the file](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#syntax-loading) `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/syntax.vim`.
4. `syntax.vim` executes the command [`:runtime syntax/synload.vim`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/f0764e8bb6511aa3bf1d6f52852b4284676ee661/runtime/syntax/syntax.vim#L19), which [will find and source](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#:runtime) the file `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/synload.vim`.
5. `synload.vim` contains [the following code](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/f0764e8bb6511aa3bf1d6f52852b4284676ee661/runtime/syntax/synload.vim#L17):

   ```
   " Set the default highlighting colors.  Use a color scheme if specified.
   if exists("colors_name")
     exe "colors " . colors_name
   ```

   `colors_name` was set in Step 1, so execution enters the `if` block, the `:colorscheme` command is run, and your colorscheme is reloaded.

If you view the output of the command [`:scriptnames`](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#:scriptnames), you should be able to trace (roughly) the execution of Vim's startup procedure through these files.

### How to fix your problem

There are several ways you could prevent the double-load, but there's a simpler and more robust method of solving your actual issue, which is that you want to ensure your cursor color is set correctly. You can do this by setting up [an autocommand that fires whenever the colorscheme is set](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#ColorScheme) e.g.:

```
augroup SetCursorColor
  autocmd!
  autocmd ColorScheme * highlight Cursor guibg=red guifg=NONE
augroup END
```

The [`pattern`](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#autocmd-patterns) is matched against the colorscheme name, so if you only want to use this cursor colour in gruvbox, you can specify this like so:

```
autocmd ColorScheme gruvbox highlight Cursor guibg=red guifg=NONE
```

Comment: According to 3.c: "Five places are searched for initializations.  The first that exists is used, the others are ignored." Since I set VIMINIT variable, only this value should be used, right? Btw, :scripts does not show that $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim is loaded. Now I tried Vim82 and got a new problem: vimrc is loaded twice :)

Comment: @user1602 Your question has changed since I wrote my answer, which addressed the original question, and which ignored the P.S. (because I didn't see it!). Did you actually have `VIMINIT` set on Windows too?

Comment: @user1602 I haven't investigated fully, but I believe your `vimrc` is loaded twice because you are setting it as your system vimrc (via its location) and then manually sourcing it with your VIMINIT.

Comment: @user1602 When you say you "got a new problem" do you mean that this is in addition to your original problem, or has it replaced it?

Comment: @user1602 Is your intention for your file to be a system or a user vimrc? If the latter, then `$VIM` is (probably, depending on how Vim was compiled) the wrong location for it. Do all your problems go away if you change the environment variable you are using to e.g. `$NOTVIM`?

Comment: @user1602 In addition to all the above, could you please add the output of `:scriptnames` into your question (or link to it from a comment).

Comment: Sorry for all the confusion and changes to the original problem. I added extra variable to the experiment: VIMINIT and it seems like changed the behavior with loading vimrc twice, which is unexpected to me.

Comment: @user1602 No worries, I just want to help you resolve your issues! Setting VIMINIT changes the behaviour because it means that your file is read a second time as a user vimrc. Because you now have a user vimrc, the defaults file is no longer read. But the root problem of `$VIM/vimrc` specifying a system vimrc (when I don't think that is your intention) remains.

Comment: My real goal is to use the same vimfiles and vimrc from different hosts and OS. I do not want to have a different copy of vimrc or vimfiles to achieve this. Of course I can find a work around with symbolic links, but I want to find a "pure vim" solution for this.

Comment: @user1602 You should already be able to achieve your real goal using the autocommand I describe in my answer. I'm very happy to help you find out exactly what's going on with the multiple loads (and intend to take another look when I get a minute), but your actual problem with your cursor is solved, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, the cursor problem is solved. Thank you for your help. I learned a lot during debugging this problem, and I realized I do not understand at all how $VIMINIT works :(